# Meteor 1.1.0.2 unable to deploy

Tags: node.js, cordova, deployment, meteor

I have updated all packages and meteor to the latest and am unable to deploy to *.meteor.com or a custom domain.  Everything operates fine with no errors on my local.  I am not explicitly using Cordova.  Below is the error:

```
$ meteor deploy site.com
Deploying to site.com.                    

~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
throw(ex);
^
Error: Unexpected token: eof (undefined) (line: 71, col: 0, pos: 1182042)
at Object.Future.wait (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:395:16)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:556:31
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:554:9
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at enterJob (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
at Object.forkJoin (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:531:3)
at [object Object]._.extend.minifyJs (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:818:28)
at [object Object]._.extend.make (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:509:12)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2054:14
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2099:20
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2098:7
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at Object.capture (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2040:31)
at Object.bundleAndDeploy (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/deploy.js:405:32)
at Command.main.registerCommand.name [as func] (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/commands.js:1168:29)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/main.js:1363:23
- - - - -
at Object.Future.wait (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:395:16)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:556:31
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:554:9
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at enterJob (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
at Object.forkJoin (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:531:3)
at _minify (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:931:18)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:820:16
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:537:23
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at enterJob (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:536:24
at runWithEnvironment (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:139:21)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:146:14
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:549:11
- - - - -

Error
at new JS_Parse_Error (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:196:18)
at js_error (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:204:11)
at croak (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:674:9)
at token_error (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:682:9)
at unexpected (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:688:9)
at block_ (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1000:28)
at ctor.body (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:974:25)
at function_ (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:979:15)
at expr_atom (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1187:24)
at maybe_unary (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/minifiers/npm/minifiers/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1357:19)
at Object.Future.get (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:196:86)
at Object.Future.wait (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:395:16)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:556:31
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:554:9
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at enterJob (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
at Object.forkJoin (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:531:3)
at _minify (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:931:18)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:820:16
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:537:23
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:352:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:345:34
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:343:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at enterJob (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:536:24
at runWithEnvironment (~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:139:21)
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:146:14
at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1rs2u00++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:549:11
```

Comment: surely the name of your app isn't actually `site.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems one of the packages I was using operated fine in local but prevented deploying and bundling.  (In this case `sahina:flatui`)

Comment: How did you fix it? I got the same problem, also using flatui.

Comment: removed flatui package and just put the css file in to my project

Comment: i just downgrade meteor version from 1.1.0.2 to 1.0.3.2

Answer (score 1):

I just downgraded meteor version from 1.1.0.2 to 1.0.3.2 . Then it works. I didn't remove flatui. Just use

```
meteor update --release METEOR@1.0.3.2
```

Comment: Everything I needed was in the flatui.css file from their github so it was better for me to remove the package and go with that.  Ideally a new package should be made by someone who will keep it up to date.